# Amending the space of total in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, siunitx

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l S S }
  ww          &  50000 &        \\
  qq          & 200000 &        \\
  dd          &  80000 &        \\
  ff          &  70000 &        \\
  \cline{2-3}
              &        & 400000 \\
  \cline{2-3}
  Pain        & 162310 &        \\
  Comp        & 100000 &        \\
  Colo        &  30000 &        \\
  LED         &  10000 &        \\
  \cline{2-3}
              &        & 302310 \\
  \cline{2-3}
                                \\
  Grand Total &        & 702310
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Problems to be resolved:

- The grand total/Total is separated to the right by a large distance in the table.
- When using SI Units in the description of the table column as `S` if there is a column header in text, an error is thrown up, how to work around this.
- How to assign one of  my table column as `S` for SI Units as well as assign the same column a fixed width by using`p{1cm}`?

[image]

Comment: Regarding the first problem: How should latex hyphenate something like "blablaccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"? Also what's the purpose of the minipage (and the quote environment)? Regarding the second problem: What's the desired alignment? To summarize: Please add a sketch of the desired output to your question.

Comment: the font warning is because you are requesting bold caps-and-small-caps and the default font set has no such fomt so you get normal bold, for the rest you specify a 3cm minipage but put in a massive table and a very long "word" that can not be hyphenated in english so naturally it does not fit.  You need to make the minipage wider or the content narrower, it is your choice: TeX can not decide that for you.

Comment: I suspect want you want is \resizebox (graphicx) or \adjustbox (adjustbox) instead of minipage.

Comment: edited large text in minipage

Comment: edited again to make it clearer

Comment: That code does not produce that image.  What happened to the first column?  This site really only works when there is one question per post.  Several "problems to be resolved" doesn't work when someone posts an answer that addresses only some of the problems, and it really breaks things when you edit away one of those problems as resolved.

Comment: @Teepeemm edited the image of the output to give the full view.

Comment: A -1 for asking a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=6.0]} } % <---
    \toprule
xxxx        &   {xxx}   &   {xxx}   \\       % <---
    \midrule
ww      &   50000   &           \\
ww      &   50000   &           \\
qq      &   200000  &           \\
dd      &   80000   &           \\
ff      &   70000   &           \\  
    \midrule
        &           &   400000  \\  
    \midrule
Pain    &   162310  &           \\
Comp    &   100000  &           \\
Colo    &   30000   &           \\
LED     &   10000   &           \\  
    \midrule
        &           &   302310  \\  
    \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{Grand Total}
                &   702310  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document
```

gives

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Regarding you last sub-question: you can put column header in multi column like

```
\multicolumn{1}{p{1cm}{<column heder>}
```

however, this means, that column be of this wide, if other contents in column will be narrowed than 1cm.

Comment: Bang On ------  @Zarko